# Hide div, if the div is empty

Tags: html, css

How can I hide a DIV (HEADER) if the DIV is empty?
here is my HTML and Style, have tried. `HEADER:empty`, but when I run the code, the DIV is still there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1920px;
}

/* Start MAIN-grid-container */
.MAIN-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1080px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 640px 300px 100px;
    grid-template-areas: "HEADER" "TOP" "MIDDLE" "FOOTER";
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /*top,right,bottom,left or auto for horizontal center*/
}

.MIDDLE { 
    grid-area: MIDDLE; 
    background-color:lightblue;
}

.FOOTER { 
    grid-area: FOOTER; 
    background-color:yellow;
}

.TOP { 
    grid-area: TOP; 
    background-color:red;
}

.HEADER { 
    grid-area: HEADER; 
    background-color:green;
}

.HEADER:empty { 
    grid-area: HEADER; 
    display: block;
}
/* End MAIN-grid-container */

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="MAIN-grid-container">
  <div class="HEADER"></div>
  <div class="TOP">
    <div class="SUB-TOP-grid-container">
      <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN" id="WeatherContainer">
        <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN-grid-container">
          <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN-TIME">DATE AND TIME<br/><br/>hhfh</div>
          <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN-CURRENT">CURRENT WEATHER</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="SUB-TOP-FORECAST">FORECAST test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can guide me, in the right direction.
As you can see the HEADER DIV is empty - but is still showed with the green background color.

UPDATE
As some of you write, then I can add this and it works..

```
.HEADER-empty, .HEADER:empty, [class^=HEADER-]:empty { 
    grid-area: HEADER; 
    display: none;
}
```

but I then get a white area over the TOP div and thats not what i'm looking for.
If the HEADER is empty, then hide the div and get the TOP div to the top.

I have then tried to use this for the TOP class-style.

```
position: fixed;
```

But the I get a white area between the TOP and MIDDLE div, can someone help me ?

Comment: use display:none; or visibility:hidden;

Comment: how do you *add* the content of the *header* - the answer would depend on that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No JS needed - just change display property's value in this CSS declaration block:

```
.HEADER:empty { 
    grid-area: HEADER; 
    display: none;
}
```

Look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j8avxm1k/

If you type or put anything in the div.HEADER it will be visible again

**EDIT**

Personally I prefer good old fashioned "float" property instead of using this "reinventing the wheel" kind of methods, nevertheless in order to answer your question in the comment:

Reset the grid-template-rows property and set the .HEADER height in it's **declaration** to desired size, like so:

```
.MAIN-grid-container {
/* ... */
grid-template-rows: auto 640px 300px 100px;
/* ... */
}

.HEADER { 
/* ... */
height: 100px;
/* ... */
}
```

Comment: *empty* is not *blank* - see what happens if there is a *whitespace* but essentially empty https://jsfiddle.net/2x53euwL/

Comment: `div:empty` matches `<div></div>` but not `<div> </div>` (note the whitespace)...

Comment: Hi AZ, can see you get the same as me, the div is not displayed... but there is then added a white area at the top, so the TOP div is not at the "TOP"-page.
Can I do something so if HEADER div is empty, then the TOP div, will be at the top.

Comment: by empty I mean empty. If a div contains a string with a whitespace - it's not essentially empty (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9bebc402beef7758147c0c8f6752277fbcfeb82a)

Answer (score 6):

The :empty pseudo selector will select elements that contain either nothing or only an HTML comment.

```
div:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

For more details please refer https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/
This may help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript to achieve that... look at the example below.
If you write somehting in the div it appears. If you have it empty, it disappears.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("HEADER");

if(x.innerHTML === ""){
    x.style.display = "none";
}
else{
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1920px;
}

/* Start MAIN-grid-container */
.MAIN-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1080px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 640px 300px 100px;
    grid-template-areas: "HEADER" "TOP" "MIDDLE" "FOOTER";
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /*top,right,bottom,left or auto for horizontal center*/
}

.MIDDLE { 
    grid-area: MIDDLE; 
    background-color:lightblue;
}

.FOOTER { 
    grid-area: FOOTER; 
    background-color:yellow;
}

.TOP { 
    grid-area: TOP; 
    background-color:red;
}

.HEADER { 
    grid-area: HEADER; 
    background-color:green;
}

.HEADER:empty { 
    grid-area: HEADER; 
    display: block;
}
/* End MAIN-grid-container */

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="MAIN-grid-container">
  <div class="HEADER" id="HEADER"></div>
  <div class="TOP">
    <div class="SUB-TOP-grid-container">
      <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN" id="WeatherContainer">
        <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN-grid-container">
          <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN-TIME">DATE AND TIME<br/><br/>hhfh</div>
          <div class="SUB-TOP-MAIN-CURRENT">CURRENT WEATHER</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="SUB-TOP-FORECAST">FORECAST test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to hide empty DIV. Suppose you have these DIVs.

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item">some text</div>
```

Simple use jQuery as:

```
$('div.item:empty').hide();
```

In your case

```
$('div.HEADER:empty').hide();
```

All empty DIVs will hide if these are empty.

For more details of jQuery [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector